# How to send data from SELECT to INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know how to put SELECT $device_dep in  INSERT query.

```
    $fprint_id = (int)$_GET['fprint_id'];
    $device_uid = $_GET ['device_uid'];
    $serialnumber = (int)$_GET['serialnumber'];

    $stmtdevice_dep = $conn->prepare("SELECT device_dep FROM devices WHERE device_uid = '$device_uid' LIMIT 1");
    //*PHP magic*
    $sqlINSERTquery = "INSERT INTO users (fprint_id, serialnumber, user_date, device_uid, device_dep, del_f, add_f) 
        VALUES ($fprint_id, $serialnumber, CURDATE(), $device_uid, $device_dep, 0, 1 LIMIT 1)";



    $db->query($sqlINSERTquery);
```

MySQL Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `devices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `device_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `device_dep` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `device_uid` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `device_date` date NOT NULL,
  `device_mode` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

I tried this:

```
   $stmtdevice_dep  = $conn->prepare("SELECT device_dep FROM devices WHERE device_uid = '$device_uid'");
    $stmtdevice_dep->execute();
    $resultdevice_dep = $stmtdevice_dep->get_result()->fetch_all();

    print_r($resultdevice_dep);
```

Return Error - Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in

**print_r($stmtdevice_dep);**
Returned:

```
mysqli_stmt Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 0
    [insert_id] => 0
    [num_rows] => 0
    [param_count] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )

    [sqlstate] => 00000
    [id] => 1
)
```

Comment: `print_r($stmtdevice_dep)` and see what was the result from query

Comment: What have you tried yet, where are you stuck?

Comment: Your first prepared statement failed, according to the error. Turn on database error reporting to find out exactly why - depending if you're using mysqli or PDO there is a different command to do this...either way you can easily find it by search. Https://phpdelusions.net has guides for both libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can get value **device_dep** from sql result using
`$stmtdevice_dep['device_dep']` **(If sql query return response in object format)** and also directly use in insert sql query